# After running this code in python this error keeps appearing

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

After running this code in python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpmath import *
h=100
k=0.1

y = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,100)

f = lambda y: (h/k)*(1- sech(0.5 * k**0.5) * cosh(y * k**0.5))
fp = f(y)

plt.plot(fp,y)
plt.xlabel('f')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlim(0, 13)
plt.ylim(-0.5, 0.5)
plt.legend(['Analytical'])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I had the following error:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (100,)

Comment: `plt.plot(f[y],y)`?

Comment: You're defining `f` as a lambda function but not calling it

Comment: @ Quang Hoang 
not working

Comment: For a start, change `y` to produce only 11 points.  Then print both it and `fp`.  Make sure those two arrays work and look reasonable.  Then go on to produce the plot.  Write you code in small testable pieces.

Comment: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
@ hpaulj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seemed to be with the `mpmath` module (which I've never used it)

Just changing the trigonometric operations to native numpy got the job done-

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
h=100
k=0.1

y = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,100)

f = lambda y: (h/k)*(1- (1/np.cosh(0.5 * k**0.5)) * np.cosh(y * k**0.5))
fp = f(y)

plt.plot(fp,y)
plt.xlabel('f')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlim(0, 13)
plt.ylim(-0.5, 0.5)
plt.legend(['Analytical'])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]